# Handling legend symbols in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'd like to put a point from another data frame (`interval`) using a square instead of a circle (without a link line). P.S.: I'd like to put the three legends (squared, the line and the black point-line).

```
test <- data.frame(Polygonal = runif(10), Real = 0.5, Sides = 3 : 12)
interval <- data.frame(x = 2,interval = 2)

ggplot(data = test, aes(x = Sides)) + 
  geom_point(aes(y = Polygonal, colour = 'Polygonal')) +
  #desired put the point withou link line and squared instead circle.
  #geom_point(aes(x = x, y = interval), shape = 23, fill = "white", color = "black") + 
  geom_line(aes(y = Polygonal, colour = 'Polygonal')) +
  geom_line(aes(y = Real, colour = 'Real')) + 
  scale_colour_manual('', breaks = c('Polygonal', 'Real'), 
                      values = c('Polygonal' = 'black', 'Real' = 'gray')) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(3, 12, 1), limits = c(2, 12)) +
  xlab('Vertices (L)') + ylab('Variance') + 
  guides(color = guide_legend(override.aes = list(pch = c(16, NA)))) +
  theme_bw()
```

## Update

I put the dot, but the caption is incorrect (with a dash in `Interval`). See figure.

```
ggplot(data = df, aes(x = Sides)) + 
  geom_point(aes(y = Polygonal, colour = 'Polygonal')) +
  geom_point(aes(x = 2, y = int_var, colour = 'Interval'), shape = 23, fill = "black") + 
  geom_line(aes(y = Polygonal, colour = 'Polygonal')) +
  geom_line(aes(y = Real, colour = 'Real')) + 
  scale_colour_manual('', breaks = c('Interval', 'Polygonal', 'Real'), 
                      values = c('Interval' = 'black', 'Polygonal' = 'gray', 'Real' = 'black')) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(3, S, 2), limits = c(2, S)) +
  xlab('Vertices (L)') + ylab('Variance') + 
  guides(color = guide_legend(override.aes = list(pch = c(23, 16, NA)))) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Comment: `int_var = 0.18` is a integer. I don't use the `data.frame`.

Comment: Take care to always offer really reproducible examples.  Your second plot has a variable called "S", which you didn't provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this adding a `linetype` parameter in the list inside the `guide_legend()` to override lines on legend like the `pch`.

For example, the first plot you make looks like this:

[image]

Adding `linetype=c(0,1)` to the code we get this legend style:

```
ggplot(data = test, aes(x = Sides)) + 
  geom_point(aes(y = Polygonal, colour = 'Polygonal')) +
  geom_line(aes(y = Polygonal, colour = 'Polygonal')) +
  geom_line(aes(y = Real, colour = 'Real')) + 
  scale_colour_manual('', breaks = c('Polygonal', 'Real'), 
                      values = c('Polygonal' = 'black', 'Real' = 'gray')) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(3, 12, 1), limits = c(2, 12)) +
  xlab('Vertices (L)') + ylab('Variance') + 
  guides(color = guide_legend(override.aes = list(pch = c(16, NA),
                                                  linetype = c(0,1)))) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

You can do the same with your last code, which should include `linetype = c(0,1,1)`